# Formatting monetary values - search and replace / Regex?

Tags: regex, currency, replace

I wonder if anyone can help with this?  I've got text documents (that have gone through a dictation/transcription package) with amounts of money that need to be put in the correct format.

Original:  $1489.05 >> Should be $1,149.05

Original:  $1489 >> Should be $1,489.00

Original:  $32,000 >> Should be $32,000.00

So in other words - 
The amounts with no decimals need to have .00 added and the amounts of over 1000 need a comma added.

A slight complication is that the amounts of over 10 000 already have a comma.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: We don't know what language you're using.  Regular expressions don't live on their own.  They are implemented by something.

Comment: @Andy - It's still possible to give an answer. It may need slight tweaking, usually only needing to choose between `/1` and `$1` in the replacement string. But, yes, it's a good idea to state the language the solution is to be implemented in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: Modified with extra step to cater for missing `$`**
**Edit: Modified steps 1 & 2 to cater for the occasional missed `,` with missing `$`**

This needs to be done in three steps with three regexes.

**Step 1**

Use the regex pattern `(^|[^$,\d])(\d*?,?\d{3}(?:[^\d]|$))` with the replacement string `\1$\2`.

This will fix the missing dollar signs.

**Step 2**

Use the regex pattern `(\$\d+)(\d{3})` with the replacement string `\1,\2`.

This will fix the missing commas.

**Step 3**

Use the regex pattern `(\$[0-9,]++)(?!\.)` with the replacement string `\1.00`.
(If your regex engine doesn't support possessive quantifiers, use the alternative pattern
`(\$[0-9,]+)(?![0-9.,])`.)

This will fix the missing cents.

**Note** These work for [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/index.html) (and other applications that are use PCRE). You may have to tweak the replacement string to suit other regex engines as some use `$1` or even `\\1` instead of `\1`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I am very new to this - is there any chance you can point me to step by step instructions on how to implement this on a Mac?  I need to find and change the figures in a whole lot of text documents and save the changed docs.  Is there an interface that will help me do this?

Comment: @RexTheRunt - I'm assuming you know how to search and replace text in an application like word? You can use regexes in the same way in a word processor/text editor that allows them. For lots of documents I would recommend the free [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/index.html). It has an excellent Multi-File Replacing feature and a good regex (Grep) introduction in the manual. I have tweaked my answer to suit it. If you need more help I can append a quick tutorial.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll get going.  I'm using something called TextSoap for general search and replace stuff, but as far as I can tell it won't let me use Grep.  I then used InDesign for the more advanced grep stuff, but it meant importing and placing all the word docs which was counter-productive time-wise.  I'll give the wrangler a go...and get back to you if I get stuck.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23376/discussion-between-robincts-and-rextherunt)